# How to Convert Image Url Into pdf, when generating PDF?

Tags: ios, image, pdf

I am successfully displaying text, but how can i display image in the pdf file ?

Actually I am new to pdf conversion

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do it this way, my basic image is in a NSData object:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2480, 3508), nil);

UIImage *aImg = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(aImg, 0.5);
CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpegData);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, aImg.size.width, aImg.size.height)];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
return pdfData;
```

Comment: how to convert NSMutableData to NSString??  I am strucked at this point??? Thanks A lot

Comment: But how to display in pdf

Comment: in a webview, for example